# Export and import data using defintion groups

Tags: axapta, data-migration, dynamics-ax-2012

I created a definition group and selected `INVENTTABLE` for export (with some filter criteria to select only a few data sets). Importing the export-file on another AX (cloned before creating data) gives no errors, but the articles are not shown in the specific masks. If I check the table on the database, all exported/imported data sets can be found.

To avoid possibly missing relations, I extended the settings of the definition group and selected related tables on level 2. Same result on the cloned machine. Data can be found in the `INVENTTABLE` but is not shown.

Any ideas how to set up export definition group correctly to make it possible to export some test data from INVENTTABLE and import them on another system in a way to be able to work with them on the target system?

It's on AX2012R3.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately since AX 2012 the data structure for items has become much more complex. It is not enough to just export data from table `InventTable`. You need a lot more tables and some of these tables reference each other by a [surrogate key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh812105.aspx). This kind of reference is not supported by the data import export feature of Dynamics AX. It is recommended to use the [Data Import Export Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj225591.aspx) to migrate such complex data structures.